# Unable to load the data from xml using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

Downloaded the data using the following command in jupyter.

```
 !7z x stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z -oposts
# load xml file into spark data frame.
posts = spark.read.format("xml").option("rowTag", "row").load("./posts/Posts.xml")
```

Got the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o532.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: xml. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:657)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass jar to the sparkContext

Jar path: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/databricks/spark-xml_2.11/0.9.0/spark-xml_2.11-0.9.0.jar

```
pyspark --jars /home/Downloads/spark_jars/spark-xml_2.11-0.9.0.jar

df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag", "row").load("./posts/Posts.xml")
```