# Read XML file in Jupiter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I tried to read an XML file in Jupiter notebook getting the below error

```
import os
from os import environ
environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.databricks:spark-xml_2.13:0.4.1 pyspark-shell'
df = spark.read.format('xml').option('rowTag', 'row').load('test.xml')
```

The error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o251.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: xml. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63243310/unable-to-load-the-data-from-xml-using-pyspark

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to load the data from xml using pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63243310/unable-to-load-the-data-from-xml-using-pyspark)